# $index in Knockout.js to show alphabets instead of numbers

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I want to use $index in KnockoutJS to show alphabets instead of numbers.e.g,

A. item1
B. item2
C. item3

How can I do this??

Comment: Your question is quite unclear... Can you add some more details maybe some code what you already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with an `ol` with a `list-style-type` of `upper-alpha`, if that suits your needs. For example:

**HTML:**

```
​<ol data-bind​​​​​​​​​​​="foreach: items" class="alpha">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ol>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**​​

```
.alpha {
    list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.items = ko.observableArray([
        "Apples",
        "Oranges",
        "Bananas"
    ]);
}
var model = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(model);​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/CCNtR/1/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/RhmTb/19/

The key is writing a View Model method to translate index to letter.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: names">
  <div>
    <span data-bind="text: $root.indexLetter($index())"></span>.
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
  </div>      
</div>
```

--

```
var viewModel = {
  names : ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'],
  indexLetter : function(index) {
    return String.fromCharCode(65 + index);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```